# hide fixed element when it reach bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i use this script to transform a menu bar to a fixed element:

```
echo "  <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function(){
var menuOffset = $('#ribbonmenu')[0].offsetTop;

$(document).bind('ready scroll', function() {
    var docScroll = $(document).scrollTop();

    if (docScroll >= menuOffset) {
        $('#ribbonmenu').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $('#ribbonmenu').removeClass('fixed');
    }

});
});//]]>
</script>";
```

The problem is that when the page is scrolled to the bottom, the fixed menu doesn't fit with the design anymore.

I need to find a way to remove the fixed attribute when the users scrolls the page to the bottom. The trigger could be either when the last 1000 pixels of the page are reached (but my pages never have the same height so it will be hard) or when it reaches a  element that i could just place where i want the menu to stop being fixed.

Any idea how i could do that?

Comment: Can you make a Fiddle? It will be easy to solve problem using it.

Comment: If you are looking for how to detect when a page is scrolled to the bottom... `document.getElementById('<scrollingDivId>').addEventListener('scroll',function(){
var obj = document.getElementById('<scrollingDivId>');
if( obj.scrollTop == (obj.scrollHeight - obj.offsetHeight)){//at bottom}},false);`

Comment: you can see it live on http://www.ni-dieu-ni-maitre.com